# Docker Bitbucket start stop at: c.a.s.i.hazelcast.HazelcastLifecycle Updating Hazelcast instance capabilities

Tags: docker

Im trying to start a bitbucketserver. Im behind a proxy and I set the proxy configuration.

Every time I try to start the container, spring stop here:

```
c.a.s.i.hazelcast.HazelcastLifecycle Updating Hazelcast instance capabilities
```

Have I to configure the proxy in Hazelcast too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the log waits here "Updating Hazelcast instance capabilities" it means its in setup page.
wget wget http://localhost:7990 in same system should download html page. now check why setup page is not showing. port might be blocked.

-Dush